# how to retrieve attributes based on each other

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

I have products with three attributes and I need to retrieve attributes based on each other. like for example if I have car make, car model and year of production and I need to first retrieve car make then for specific make I retrieve car model and for both make and model retrieve year of production. how to do do

Comment: do you want to get product based on attribute. right ?

Comment: yes and also to retrieve attributes based on each other